# Skip OSX Beta Update

Tags: software-update, macos, beta-seed-program

From reading some comments, it looks like OS X 10.11 "El Capitan" Beta 3 breaks some aspects of Java that work in Beta 2. Is there a way to skip Beta 3, but still be notified when Beta 4 comes out, i.e. not opt out of the beta program?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You get prompted to install each build, so don't click for beta 3. Once 4 arrives, you'll likely have to first jump to 3 and then jump to 4.

This is documented at http://openradar.appspot.com/22307567

Your comment about not opting out is also confusing - I'm not sure how that relates to your ability to choose whether to install a specific update.

Comment: Right, but I'd like to stop being notified about update 3.

Comment: @Adam_G   It wasn't clear you were asking that. When I upload a screenshot of the update you wish to discuss and perhaps someone can have a solution for that as well

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to install Beta 4 when it comes out. I don't think you have to be running Beta 3 in order to install it.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I reread your question and I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to stop being notified about update 3.

Comment: I'm confused about what the OP is actually asking as well, apparently